# 4k monitor flickering at full resolution

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I recently bought a 4k TV (LG 49UB820V) as a monitor for my PC.
But I have many problems with my current configuration:

1. The image is by far not sharp, which it should be on a 4k monitor
2. Whenever the mouse moves the area around the mouse flickers a lot
3. Windows and the NVidia control panel show the native resolution as 1080p, which should be 2160p

All my hardware should support 4k@60Hz, but it just does not work. I tried changing the frequency to 50, 30 and 24Hz, but that did not help either.

I am using: NVidia GTX 960 and HDMI 2.0, Driver version 347.88, Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: HDMI cable… is it v1.4 or higher? Use the one that came with the TV if you have more than 1.

Comment: I bought one which explicitly had HDMI 2.0 compatibility

Comment: Old question that just got bumped. The problem is your computer is seeing the TV as 1080p. The various symptoms are from mapping the 4K application output to 1080p, and the TV is then mapping the 1080p onto 4K. Why that's happening is the problem you need to solve. The cause isn't knowable from the symptoms; there are many potential problems in the chain. You need to systematically diagnose from one end of the chain to the other until you find it, and don't assume that components are working without verifying; e.g., just because the cable is rated for HDMI 2.0, don't assume it isn't defective.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cable is compatible with 4k:

http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_2_0/hdmi_2_0_faq.aspx#119

> Does HDMI 2.0 require new cables?
>   No, HDMI 2.0 features will work with existing HDMI cables. Higher bandwidth features, such as 4K@50/60 (2160p) video formats, will require existing High Speed HDMI cables (Category 2 cables).

Comment: It is a High Speed HDMI cable. I've already tried two different cables. neither worked.